# Howto hide the text (and its lenght) that are editing?

Tags: octave-gui

I want write password of the root to the shell, but without move the cursor when i write it.

`prompt = {"Senha de Administrador: "};` your text`defaults = {""};` your text`rowscols = [1,25];

`your text`senha_root = inputdlg (prompt, "para Alterar Permissões de porta USB ", ...
`your text`                 rowscols, defaults);

I can't, for example, change the color text to the background tex, as alternative

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to hide text while editing it, depending on what you mean by "hiding" the text and the context in which you are editing the text. Here are a few options:

If you are editing text in a word processor or text editor, you can use the "hidden" text formatting feature to hide the text. This will cause the text to be invisible while you are editing, but it will be visible when the document is printed or exported.

If you are writing code and want to hide certain lines or blocks of code while you are editing, you can use a code folding feature to collapse the code so that it takes up less space in the editor.

If you are writing text on a website and want to hide it from view, you can use the "display: none" CSS style to hide the text. This will cause the text to be invisible to users, but it will still be present in the HTML code of the page.